# boolean expression from truth table

Tags: python, logic, sympy, boolean-logic, truthtable

I want to convert truth table to boolean expression :
for example , this is the table

```
a    b         a+b>0
0    1           1         
1    0           1
```

I want to get the following output:
(¬a ^b ) ∨ (a ^¬b)

I am thinking about using replace,  :

```
if (value == str(0)):
    table= table(str(value), 'not x')
else:
    table= table.replace(str(value), ' x')
```

it is not correct ,,

how can I replace the value with the column name and then check if the value is 0 or 1 ?

I am using python

Comment: Take the first row: `a=0, b=1`, `a+b=1` but `1<0` is false so I don't know why your table has 1 in it. (And if `+` is treated like `&` then a&b is also false. See `SOPform` in sympy.logic.boolalg.

Comment: I edited the table .. I tried to use SOPform but I did not get the result I wanted ..

Answer (score 0):

How did you use SOPform? I get

[image]